# Nested Renamer not supported

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

Use the following dictionary to group the Countries by Continent, then create a DataFrame that displays the sample size (the number of countries in each continent bin), and the sum, mean, and std deviation for the estimated population of each country.

```py
ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
                  'United States':'North America', 
                  'Japan':'Asia', 
                  'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
                  'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
                  'Canada':'North America', 
                  'Germany':'Europe', 
                  'India':'Asia',
                  'France':'Europe', 
                  'South Korea':'Asia', 
                  'Italy':'Europe', 
                  'Spain':'Europe', 
                  'Iran':'Asia',
                  'Australia':'Australia', 
                  'Brazil':'South America'}
```

*This function should return a DataFrame with index named Continent `['Asia', 'Australia', 'Europe', 'North America', 'South America']` and columns `['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']`*

top15 = answer_one()
ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia',
'United States':'North America',
'Japan':'Asia',
'United Kingdom':'Europe',
'Russian Federation':'Europe',
'Canada':'North America',
'Germany':'Europe',
'India':'Asia',
'France':'Europe',
'South Korea':'Asia',
'Italy':'Europe',
'Spain':'Europe',
'Iran':'Asia',
'Australia':'Australia',
'Brazil':'South America'}
top15['Continent'] = top15.index.to_series().map(ContinentDict)
top15['Population Estimate']= (top15['Energy Supply']/top15['Energy Supply per Capita']).astype(float)
result = top15.set_index('Continent').groupby(level = 0)['Population Estimate'].agg({'size':np.size, 'sum':np.sum, 'mean':np.mean,'std':np.std})
return result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The `SpecificationError` is due to the way you're making the aggregations names.

> Exception raised by agg **when** the functions are **ill-specified**: [[*docs*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.errors.SpecificationError.html)]

Not to mention that passing a dict to [`SeriesGroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.agg.html) is now deprecated (*see [GH50684](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/50684)*).

So, since you expect the columns names to be the same as the agg-functions, you can pass a list :

```
# ... .groupby(level=0)['Population Estimate'].agg(['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std'])
```

To go further, you can also simply your code this way :

```
def answer_one():
    # global top15 # ?!

    ContinentDict = {
        'China': 'Asia', 
        'United States': 'North America', 
        'Japan': 'Asia', 
        # ...
    }
    
    top15['Population Estimate']= (
        top15['Energy Supply']/top15['Energy Supply per Capita']
    )

    result = (
        top15.groupby(
            top15.index.map(ContinentDict).rename('Continent'))
            ['Population Estimate'].agg(['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std'])
    )

    return result
```